# How to access an column with special characters using DataTable.Select()?

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I have a `DataTable` with column such as `# of Students` and would like to sort by this in descending order. Here is my code:

```
...
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("# of Students", typeof(string)));

// do some stuff... add records etc.

// A runtime error occurs here: "Cannot find column '# of Students'"
var rows = dt.Select("","'# of Students' desc");

// this is just fine.
rows = dt.Select("","# of Students");
```

How can I access this column if has special characters in its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [] brackets, like this :

```
var rows = dt.Select("","[# of Students] desc");
```

Comment: Man I am a dummy! That should have been more obvious to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use both [] or `` syntax. Both following snippets are correct:

```
var rows = dt.Select("","`# of Students` desc");

var rows = dt.Select("","[# of Students] desc");
```

Comment: the backticks didn't work for me. Maybe this is new to .NET 4.0? I'm running on 3.5

Comment: Yes, its 4.0 stuff. Here is some msdn reading - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.100).aspx switch framework versions to compare the description of syntax.

Comment: However, the character ',' (comma) is present (instead '#') then it fails in both [] and ''' cases.