# Can I use special characters in column name in SQL Server and C# data table

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a doubt can I use special characters `%`, `$`, `+`, `-`, `#` in SQL Server table column name and C# data table?

I tried to create a table with these characters in SQL Server the table is created, but I want to know its possible or not?

Comment: why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Yes you can, but if you can avoid it, don't, because there's no guarantee that other tools you use will be able to read them

Comment: Really - just don't do it. Think of this as a formatting thing and do any special naming of columns in your presentation layer. Honestly, anyone who ever has to use your tables in the future will curse you.

Comment: We usually don't suggest you using special characters in column name. About you question, please see my answer.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer(on the left of my reply, there is an option to mark), thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained you can since your column name is between square brackets, but it is not a good practice use spaces and special characters in column names.

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE1] (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, [% Column1] INT, [$ Column2] INT, [+ Column3] 
INT, [- Column4] INT, [# Column5] INT);

INSERT INTO [TABLE1] (ID, [% Column1], [$ Column2], [+ Column3], [- Column4], [# Column5])
VALUES ('8C012194-5D8A-4A58-B225-F33F60875499',1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If you are using Entity Framework you can map your column to your model class like this:

```
[Table("Table1")]
public class Test 
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [Column("% Column1")]
  public int Column1 { get; set; }

  [Column("$ Column2")]
  public int Column2 { get; set; }

  [Column("+ Column3")]
  public int Column3 { get; set; }

  [Column("- Column4")]
  public int Column4 { get; set; }

  [Column("# Column5")]
  public int Column5 { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Azure sql supports these special characters in your column name.

Because the SQL Server datatype column_name  is nvarchar( 128 ). 
[image]

You can get this form this document: [COLUMNS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

For C# , as mukesh kudi said, you should use `[]` brackets.

For example, if you want to select the column with special character '#', the code should like this:

```
var rows = dt.Select("","[#]");
```

You can reference this blog: [How to access an column with special characters using DataTable.Select()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081523/how-to-access-an-column-with-special-characters-using-datatable-select)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO,You can have column name with special character or space but you have to use

> square bracket []

in order to access those columns.

eg.

```
Table
%ID
1
2
3


Select [%ID] from Table
```

For more information on column and table name rules for MSSQL Server you can check out [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-amp-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign)